# Как получить координаты элемента относительно экрана?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как получить координаты формы? Кнопки в этой форме? Относительно главного экрана

Comment: Уточните, на чем у вас сделан интерфейс?

Comment: Вчера понял, что программу придется делать на wpf, на винформ выйдет слишком дорого по ресурсам  в плане эффектов

Answer (score 2):

Координаты формы:

```
int windowTop = this.Top; 
int windowLeft = this.Left;
```

Координаты любого контрола относительно главного экрана:

```
Point location = someControl.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
```

Comment: `this.Top` — это для какого типа `this`?

Comment: @VladD при написании ответа не было метки WPF, так что это для Windows Forms, как и указано в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
 FindForm().PointToScreen(Control1.Location);
```

Answer (score 1):

Для WPF:

```
button.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
```

(где `button` — ваша кнопка) даёт координаты левого верхнего угла. Если вам нужна середина кнопки, то

```
button.PointToScreen(new Point(button.ActualWidth, button.ActualHeight));
```

Для окна вместо `button` подставьте окно.