# Получение позиции курсора мыши в окне

Tags: c#

У меня возникла такая проблема:

Есть приложение, там время от времени появляется табличка с выбором типа "да / нет".

Нужно жмякнуть "да". Пробовал наводить на кнопку, брать координаты курсора. Но! Нужно сделать типа защиты от разрешение экрана, ибо одни и те же координаты при разном разрешении расположены в разных местах.

Так вот, думаю просто взять положение курсора именно в окне. Как это сделать?

P.S Если знаете, подскажите пожалуйста, может быть есть какие-то другие пути решения проблемы?

Comment: А это окно с вашей программы или windows его выдает?

Comment: Это, по сути, игра. Windows.

Comment: @NoName_as_Null здесь ответили https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511756/Как-получить-координаты-элемента-относительно-экрана

Comment: @Digital Core, там позиция в форме, грубо говоря, в моей программе, а мне нужно в игре (gta sa)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585442/Нажать-на-кнопку-в-стороннем-приложении-используя-winapi

Comment: Посмотрите библиотеку `AutoIT` для `c#` [тут](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И так нужно получить координаты окна запущенного приложения.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool GetWindowRect(HandleRef hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
            public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
            public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
            public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("{0,4} {1,4} {2,4} {3,4}", Left, Top, Right, Bottom);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad++");
            RECT rct;
            if (!GetWindowRect(new HandleRef(null, proc[0].MainWindowHandle), out rct))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(rct.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Далее таким же образом получаем координаты окна сообщения и дочернего элемента кнопки, на этом всё.